# How to eliminate time from these equations when trying to find range of a projectile on an inclined plane?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]

I wanted to calculate the range of this projectile. I have done it using other methods but this time I assumed the ground to be the $x-axis$ and the perpendicular line stemming out of $O$ as $y-axis$. Then the linear curve along the inclned plane would be - $y=tan(\alpha)$.

For the path of the ball, I need to eliminate "t" from these two equations,
$$x=ucos(\theta)t$$
$$y=usin(\theta)t$$

(I know I'm clearly doing things wrong from this step onwards but I'm not able to articulate it well. It just feels wrong. Would be great if you guys could point it out)

We can eliminate "$t$" in this step but let's square the two equations and add them,
$$x^2+y^2=(ut)^2$$

Now, I can replace "$t$" using, $t=\frac{usin(\theta)}{g}$

But I just know I shouldn't be doing that. I shouldn't be putting a constant value of $t$ there.Again, not able to articulate myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two equations

$$x=V\cos(\theta)\,t\\
y=V\sin(\theta)\,t-\frac{g\,t^2}{2}$$

with

$$x=r\cos(\alpha)~,y=r\sin(\alpha)$$

you can solved the two equations for $~t~,r~$

you obtain the distance r , which you are looking for

$$r=-\frac{2\,V^2(\sin(\alpha)+\sin(\alpha-2\theta))}{g\,(\cos(2\alpha)+1)}$$